# Deployment of laravel project on heroku, assets are not working

Tags: laravel, heroku

I have deployed my laravel app to heroku, but my routes are not working and as i found out that I need to add `index.php` to my routes to access them and now they are accessing but my `assets css js jquery` is not working.It is my first deployment on heroku, your help is appreciated.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
      Options -MultiViews
  </IfModule>

  RewriteEngine On AllowOverride All
  # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

  # Handle Front Controller...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # Handle Authorization Header
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

While deploying to heroku you need not to add index.php to routes and other files (css/js etc ). Check if you have made any changes to htaccess file in public folder.

Comment: as i mentioned above, i have added `index.php` in my routes and they are working fine, but when i add `index.php/public/css/app.css` it is showing me laravel page `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.`

Comment: Try index.php/css/app.css

Comment: Please confirm if your Procfile is `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/ `

Comment: Yes my `Procfile` is exactly the same .

Comment: Check if mod_rewrite is enabled on heroku

Comment: Your . htaccess and Procfile are fine so it should not happen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192830/discussion-between-muhammad-shareyar-and-svikramjeet).